How to force youtube links in whatsapp to open on youtube?
This is question that has been asked many times
How to make Android 12 let me pick the app every time when opening URLs on a particular domain?
How to make YouTube URLs open in YouTube app rather than browser? (updated for 2022)
None of these work for me. I am on pixel 8a android 14. On whatsapp the youtube links such as youtu.be is forced to open on internal browser of whatsapp. Even though in open by default menu under Settings/Apps/Default Apps/Opening links/youtube has options set to open in supported links.
Is this getting blocked from someplace else? Or has apps like whatsapp or facebook or firefox hijacked the ability to open youtube links directly in youtube.

I may be wrong but I don't see any permission or app ops or activity that controls this, so even on a rooted device it isn't possible. IMO, it's because that Whatsapp doesn't expose the API or whatever to the user, it's a closed Box leaving with a double tap option -tap to play in WhatsApp and tap the second time on the YouTube icon to open in YouTube
